# looking for a more elegant way to solve this task

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new in Angular and I'm looking for a more elegant way to solve this task.

Code bellow works fine, but I'm not sure that is a right way to make it done.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="ngFilterApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <p>Filtering input:</p>

    <p><input type="text" ng-model="search" /></p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names | myFilter">
            {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var searchVal;
angular.module('CustomFilterModule', [])
  .filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function( input ) {
    searchVal = searchVal || '';
    var s = searchVal.toLowerCase();
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if(input[i].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) === 0 || input[i].country.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) === 0) arr.push(input[i]);
    }

    return arr;
  };
});

angular.module('ngFilterApp', ['CustomFilterModule'])
  .controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = [
    {name:'Moscow',country:'Russia'},
    {name:'Kiev',country:'Ukraine'},
    {name:'Yerevan',country:'Armenia'},
    {name:'Washington',country:'USA'},
    {name:'Madrid',country:'Spain'},
    {name:'Tbilisi',country:'Georgia'}
  ];

  $scope.$watch('search', function() { searchVal = $scope.search; }, true);
});
```

**JSBIN** http://jsbin.com/bomotocota/edit?html,js,output

Comment: There is a stackexchange site for [code reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gifatoyilo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks, I really didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the query string in to the filter as an argument, see modified JSBIN:

http://jsbin.com/yivomusoso/edit?html,js,output